# How to fix .ejs file not including css stylings

Tags: css, node.js, express

I am creating a webpage locally and trying to link the css file to all of the .ejs files through a header file. It successfully links for 2 out of 3 of the files, but my last file cannot get the style sheet's styles.

All of the other stackoverflow questions relating to this seem to be not able to link css at all, but I can. I can't see it being an issue with my css or header files since those do work for some, so I imagine it has to do with my app.js file, but the code seems virtually identical to the video tutorials I'm following along with.

Header.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>YelpCamp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/yelpcamp.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <a href="/"><button class="navbutton">YelpCamp</button></a>
    <a><button class="navbutton">Login</button></a>
    <a><button class="navbutton">Sign Up</button></a>
    <a><button class="navbutton">Logout</button></a>
</nav>
```

new.ejs (css does not work when this file is accessed)

```
<% include partials/header %>

<main>
    <h1>Create A New Campground</h1>
    <form id="newcamp" method="POST" action="/campgrounds">
        <input type="text" name="name" required>
        <input type="url" name="url" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
</main>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

campgrounds.ejs (css works with this file)

```
<% include partials/header %>

<div id="container">

    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp!</h1>
        <p>View our hand-picked campgrounds from all over the world</p>
        <a href="/campgrounds/new"><button>Add New Campground</button></a>
    </header>

    <main>
        <% campgrounds.forEach( campground => { %>
        <figure>
            <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
            <figcaption><strong><%= campground.name %></strong></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <% }); %>
    </main>

</div>
```

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const campgrounds = [
    {name: "Banff", image: "images/banff.jpg"},
    {name: "Jasper", image: "images/jasper.JPG"},
    {name: "Mosquito Creek", image: "images/mosquito_creek.jpg"}
];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("landing_page");
});

app.get("/campgrounds", (req, res) => {
    res.render("campgrounds", {campgrounds: campgrounds});
});

app.post("/campgrounds", (req, res) => {
    campgrounds.push({name: req.body.name, image: req.body.url});
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", (req, res) => {
    res.render("new");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
});
```

File Structure
.
+---public 
|---+---css
|---+---yelpcamp.css
|---+---images
+---views
|---+---partials
|---|---+---footer.ejs
|---|---+---header.ejs
|---+---campgrounds.ejs
|---+---landing_page.ejs
|---+---new.ejs
+---app.js

Comment: change relative url `href="css/yelpcamp.css"` to absolute `href="/css/yelpcamp.css"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you explain why the relative url wouldn't work for the new.ejs file since it is in the same directory as the other files?

Comment: cause when You navigate to `http://someurl/campgrounds`  base root url for related url changes and it becomes: `http://someurl/campgrounds/css/yelpcamp.css`. so when You define absolute url it points to root `/`. watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGM0uacxqnc

Comment: Thanks! Cheers m8 :)